# How do I find which version of Python to use with Mercurial?

Tags: python, windows, mercurial, version

I read [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) that

> On Windows, your Python version *must* match the version used to compile Mercurial. Otherwise, you'll get "Invalid Magic Number" errors when trying to run the CGI.  The pre-compiled Windows binaries for Mercurial 1.0.x, 1.1.x, 1.2.x and 1.3.x were compiled with Python 2.5.

I looked online but I dont see a lookup table for this information.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Windows you want to install [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io). It provides the full Mercurial command line, a GUI with Windows shell integration, and the right version of Python all compiled in together.

Comment: Ah ok cool, yeah looks like from the FAQ (http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/1.1/faq.html), `TortoiseHg includes an entire Python distribution bundled up as DLLs.`  Good to know

Answer (score 1):

The various HG installation packages have the required Python version in their name. You can also look it up in the release notes for the package.

Comment: Ok, I can see here (http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/windows/) that some of them have the versions in them, but for example, the latest 1.7 does not.  Do you have a link to what you are looking at?

Comment: Yes. These wiki entries: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UpgradingMercurial and http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UpgradeNotes